# Airtable: Join two tables into a unified master output

Tags: view, airtable

I have data in two different linked tables in Airtable and I need to join them together. See example:

The PERSON table looks like:

```
Name  |  Classes
----------------
John  | A,B,C,F
Sally | B,F
Max   | B,C
```

While the linked CLASSES table looks like:

```
Class | Date | People
---------------------------
A     | 1975 | John
B     | 2000 | John,Sally,Max
C     | 1823 | John,Max
D     | 1492 |
E     | 2020 |
F     | 2010 | John,Sally
```

What I need is:

```
Person|Class|Date
--------------
John  | A   | 1975
John  | B   | 2000
John  | C   | 1823
John  | F   | 2010
Sally | B   | 2000
Sally | F   | 2010
Max   | B   | 2000
Max   | C   | 1823
```

How do I get this view / table as output?

Answer (score 2):

The more I see questions like this, with no answer, the more I realise how airtable just isn't a database in any real sense.

This is a perfectly reasonable question about how to join 2 tables after those tables have been normalised.  Answer?  It can't be done, not easily!

So what is airtable supposed to be used for, building non-normalised databases, otherwise known as a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0):

- If you use click "Class" field like "A" or "B" in the "Person" table, it'll show the popup so that you could see the class details.
- Or if you really want to need that kind of table, my suggestion is like this
  Create a new table called "xxx", and write the code in the scripting block and populate the data from "Person", "Class" tables to the new table.

PS: Scripting block is only supported in the "Pro" plan.